# Immobilize content while scroll and sticky nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have simple lay here https://maniek9101.github.io/test-repo/   but ...

When scrolling the page down and fixing the navigation, I add a padding-top to the content of the page so that the text does not jump because of the position change for navigation. When scrolling down, the text responds nicely and doesn't move, but from bottom to top when you change the navigation from fixed to the default one, you can notice a slight skipping of the text in the`content` I have no idea what the reason is and how to remedy it .

I will appreciate the help!

Comment: it could be the padding top that it's added programatically to the `content`

Comment: But i remove this padding, while scroll from bottom to top

Comment: when i scrolled from top to bottom, what I saw is that the title "We help companies..." jumps due to the padding top being added. you could try to make the nav position absolute, and when the class fix is added, make it sticky and without adding padding-top to the content